# Golang - Reusing custom composable methods from structs around map type

Tags: go, inheritance, methods, maps, composable

In the example shown on the image, I expected method Put to apply on MappingStringInt since it is composed from Mapping. However, this is not the case.
If Mapping was composed with type struct, method Put will apply on MappingStringInt.
Is there a way to fix this and make line 20 on the image to work?
thanks

[Golang - Reusing custom composable methods from structs around map type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9hCw.png)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    Mapping[K comparable, V any] map[K]V
    MappingStringInt             Mapping[string, int]
)

func (self Mapping[K, V]) Put(key K, value V) Mapping[K, V] {
    self[key] = value
    return self
}
func main() {
    m1 := Mapping[string, int]{"two": 2}
    m1.Put("four", 4) // Works
    fmt.Printf("Mapping(four = %v) %+v \n", m1["four"], m1)

    m2 := MappingStringInt{"two": 2}
    m2.Put("four", 4) // Fails: m2.Put undefined (type MappingStringInt has no field or method Put)
    fmt.Printf("Mapping(four = %v) %+v \n", m2["four"], m2)
}
```

I tried using references on the method but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share code as properly formatted text, don't post pictures of code.

Comment: This is how the language is specified. If you define a new type, methods of the base type will not be available for the derived type. To do what you want, embed the base type in a struct type.

Comment: @BurakSerdar If we use embedding, we loose the underlying map functionality like accessing values with [] notation directly on the root object. Thus we can't do stuff like: m1["four"] without going two levels deep like m2.Mapping["four"].

Answer (score 0):

As [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar) mentioned in comment, it will not be derived from the type but you can embed it in struct as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type (
    Mapping[K comparable, V any] map[K]V

    MappingStringInt struct {
        Mapping[string, int]
    }
)

func (item Mapping[K, V]) Put(key K, value V) {
    item[key] = value
}

func main() {
    m1 := Mapping[string, int]{"two": 2}
    m1.Put("four", 4) // Works
    fmt.Printf("Mapping(four = %v) %+v \n", m1["four"], m1)

    m2 := MappingStringInt{Mapping: Mapping[string, int]{"two": 2}}
    m2.Put("three", 3)
    fmt.Printf("Mapping(four = %v) %+v \n", m2.Mapping["four"], m2)
}
```

Comment: If we use embedding, we loose native map functionality on m1. We will have to do m2.Mapping["four"] instead of m2["four"]

Comment: Then I think you will have to go with individual Put declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a new type, the methods declared for the base type will not be available for the derived type. To use the methods declared for a type, you have to embed it into a new struct type.

One thing you can do is to use type aliases:

```
type MappingStringInt = Mapping[string, int]
```

Then, `MappingStringInt` is not a new type, but an alias for `Mapping[string,int]`, and you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Creating aliases for generic types is not yet supported by Golang. There is an open issue on GitHub regarding generic type aliases. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46477

Comment: @nkwati, for this specific case, it appears to be working: https://go.dev/play/p/IjQLrZOHsrP

Comment: It works because the alias is not generic. MappingStringInt                  = Mapping[string, int] is not generic. An alias simple points to another struct which in this case is Mapping[K comparable, V any]